# Folder is not creating in bin-debug.

Tags: apache-flex

I have a problem with Flash builder 4.5. I added a new folder containing images, and when I run the project, no images folder creates in bin-debug ?!

My folder is on src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring up the project properties in your Flash Builder project.  Then select Flex Compiler.

Look for a Checkbox entitled "Copy non-embedded files to output folder."  Make sure it is checked.  IF not, then the compiler will not move non-embedded images to your bin-debug [or bin-release] folders.